# How to play game with wifi only using Game Center?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

I am new to game center and using game center and to get the local wifi players CKMatchmaker provides the method

```
-startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandle
```

but i dont know where to use this method.How would i get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial here:[multiplayer gaming with game center](http://upyun.cocimg.com/upload/g2/2012/10/session_519__multiplayer_gaming_with_game_center.pdf). Here is Apple's doc on [GKMatchmaker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).